# Como usar executorservice

Tags: java, hilos, executorservice

Tengo un arrayList, donde me guardo 12 valores [1 o 0], según si el error esta activado o no (siendo 0 desactivado y 1 activado).

```
public void rellenar() {
    cont = 0;
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(0, getVibrador1Reponer());//vibrador 1 reponer
    list.add(1, getVibrador1Atasco());//vibrador 1 atasco
    list.add(2, getVibrador2Reponer());//vibrador 2 reponer
    list.add(3, getVibrador2Atasco());//vibrador 2 atasco
    list.add(4, getVibrador3Reponer());//vibrador 3 reponer
    list.add(5, getVibrador3Atasco());//vibrador 3 atasco
    list.add(6, getVibrador4Reponer());//vibrador 4 reponer
    list.add(7, getVibrador4Atasco());//vibrador 4 atasco
    list.add(8, getVibrador4Reponer());//vibrador 5 reponer
    list.add(9, getVibrador4Atasco());//vibrador 5 atasco
    list.add(10, getVibrador4Reponer());//vibrador 6 reponer
    list.add(11, getVibrador4Atasco());//vibrador 6 atasco
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).equals("1")) {
            cont++;

        }
    }
    System.out.println("total de Hilos a crear son: " + cont);
    zonaFallos();//ejecuta los audios segun la zona del error 
    System.out.println("____________________________________________________");
}
```

Bien ahora comprueba si el error esta activado o no (todo esto lo voy comprobando a tiempo real)

```
private void zonaFallos() {
    if (list.get(0).equals("1")) {
        audioVibrador.playFalloVibrador1Reponer();
    }
    if (list.get(1).equals("1")) {
        audioVibrador.playFalloVibrador1Atasco();
    }
    if (list.get(2).equals("1")) {
        audioVibrador.playFalloVibrador2Reponer();
    }
    if (list.get(3).equals("1")) {
        audioVibrador.playFalloVibrador2Atasco();
    }
    if (list.get(4).equals("1")) {
        audioVibrador.playFalloVibrador3Reponer();
    }
    if (list.get(5).equals("1")) {
        audioVibrador.playFalloVibrador3Atasco();
    }
    if (list.get(6).equals("1")) {
        audioVibrador.playFalloVibrador4Reponer();
    }
    if (list.get(7).equals("1")) {
        audioVibrador.playFalloVibrador4Atasco();
    }
    if (list.get(8).equals("1")) {
        audioVibrador.playFalloVibrador5Reponer();
    }
    if (list.get(9).equals("1")) {
        audioVibrador.playFalloVibrador5Atasco();
    }
    if (list.get(10).equals("1")) {
        audioVibrador.playFalloVibrador6Reponer();
    }
    if (list.get(11).equals("1")) {
        audioVibrador.playFalloVibrador6Atasco();
    }
}
```

Se ejecuta un audio dando el aviso secuencialmente.

Necesito crear una tarea por cada aviso de 30 segundos, para que no sea tan repetitivo.(y que no se ejecute la tarea a la vez, ya que el audio se solapara)
La tarea se ejecutara cada vez que lance un aviso (a 1) , y se cancelara la tarea cuando se solucione el fallo.(a 0).
Me han comentado que gaste "executorservice", pero no se como empezar... 
Os agradecería vuestra ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberias utilizar [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Necesitas hacer 3 cosas:

1. Implementar Runnable en la clase que invocaras desde ScheduledExecutorService.
2. Obtener una instancia del ScheduledExecutorService.
3. Lanzar la tarea

Algo asi:

```
// la clase
class MiClase implements Runnable {

    void run() {
         zonaFallos();
    }

    // declaracion de zonaFallos()
}

// donde 1 es la cantidad maxima de tareas simultaneas
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

MiClase target = new MiClase();

// esto lo lanza cada 30 segundos exactos
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(target, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// esto lo lanza con 30 segundos de diferencia entre ejecuciones.
scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(target, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

La primera opcion, ejecuta la tarea exactamente cada 30 segundos, si la misma no termino en esos 30 segundos, lanzara otra vez la tarea (si hay suficientes Threads en el pool del `ScheduledExecutorService`).

La segunda opcion, evita que se ejecuta la tarea mas de una vez en simultaneo ya que calcula los 30 segundos a partir de que termino la ejecucion anterior.

### Cancelar la tarea

Hay 2 formas:

Una es invocando a `shutdown` del Scheduler.

```
 scheduler.shutdown();
```

La otra es tomando una `ScheduledFuture<?>` task cuando creas la tarea y cancelandola manualmente.

```
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(target, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// luego cuando la quieres cancelar
scheduledFuture.cancel(false); // false evita que lanze una interrupcion.
```

Salu2